# Is assistancy a word? If not, what's a better alternative?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology, software-bugs

Today, I wanted to discuss a role I had as a research assistant at a university. I had discussed it using language like "During my research assistancy, I did xyz" or "I had this experience in my research assistancy." Compare to the equivalent sentences with "PhD candidacy" instead, which I hear from time to time.

When I tried to use assistancy in a later email, it was underlined red. To my surprise, many dictionaries don't have that word, including Merriam-Webster, dictionary.com, the Cambridge Dictionary, and the Oxford Learner's Dictionaries. Spellchecker.net even [lists it as a spelling mistake](https://www.spellchecker.net/misspellings/assistancy).

The Google Books Ngram Viewer does [list usages of it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assistancy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cassistancy%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cassistancy%3B%2Cc0), but only barely, and the word seems to have fallen out of (relative) popularity 100 years ago.

Given this information, can "assistancy" be considered a word? For reference, the similar term **candidacy** [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candidacy):

> the state of being a candidate

If assistancy is indeed unacceptable, what word means "the state of being an *assistant*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to avoid a useful word because it is not widely defined, you could use a related alternative:

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/assistantship)
>
> **assistantship**: in British English NOUN US education:
>
> a graduate post which requires the student to carry out some teaching duties in return for financial assistance

Interestingly, *assistanceship* does not appear in many other dictionaries than Collins, so might suffer the same way as *assistancy* were it not for Google ngram's showing a pattern of its sustained use from the mid 1800s: ten times the occurrence of *assistancy* over almost ten times the period, extending to the present day.

Comment: **Assistency** appears in the OED but the sense is "helpfulness" rather than a post or duty. Furthermore, it is marked as "obsolete" - last recorded c.1675. You will probably have to rephrase: "During my time as a research assistant ..."

Comment: Ah, this seems to be what I was looking for. It is somewhat inaccurate for how I tried to use it since my research assistantship is unpaid and as an undergraduate (I hadn't specified that in my question, apologies), but I think bending this term wouldn't be too much of a stretch for that. I'll accept this answer after some time if nothing more fitting comes along.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what your last paragraph is supposed to mean, comparing assistancy to assistancy. Perhaps you made a typo?

Comment: @DrakeP Oops, Yes you are quite correct. Many Thanks for that. I hate typing on an iPad - much more reliable on the laptop.

Comment: You should fix your answer. assistantship is also used in AmE.

Answer (score 0):

**assistancy** (n.)

> Forms:  Also 1600s–1700s **assistency**.
>
> The position of an assistant.
>
> 1608   T. Fitzherbert *Let*. 23 Aug. (1948) 29   You have confirmed Mr
> Singleton in his Assistency
>
> 1909   *Practitioner* Nov. 723   Qualified men..are..not available for
> assistancy work. (OED)

However, I don't see it spelled either way in Google Books in modern times with that meaning, and I would definitely avoid it in a resume.

---

> The following managerial changes have been made: George F. Peer is
> promoted from an **assistancy** at Newark to the managership of Dover;
> Patrick Hughes advances from an **assistancy** in New York to the
> managership of Hoboken ... [*The Insurance Times*, Vol. 34](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Insurance_Times/PoBIAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=assistancy&pg=PA21&printsec=frontcover) (1901)

> This problem is to be solved by recourse to an **assistancy** or by
> securing a place on the staff of an available hospital. In an
> **assistancy** a man may become an operator and lay the foundation for a very considerable success in the practice of surgery. [*Iowa Medical
> Journal, Vol. 16*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Iowa_Medical_Journal/DoxMAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=assistancy&pg=PA355&printsec=frontcover) (1909)

Comment: ”An assistancy is a large geographical area comprising several Jesuit provinces, most of whose inhabitants speak a common language. There were four assistancies [Italy, Germany, Portugal, and Spain] in 1600. The assistancy of France was added in 1608, and Poland and Lithuania in 1755.’

Comment: @tchrist Yes, that usage is actually more common, but appears to often be capitalized. // I also found "The returns of every agent in his assistancy each week are reviewed by him before being sent to the home office" in a life-insurance publication.